# How to have same proportions in a SwiftUI List row?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

Being a Swift newbie I do not understand how to fix the layout problem -

[image: screenshot]

As you can see in the above screenshot, the proportions between the name, the game stats and the photo change with each row.

In my [custom View](https://github.com/afarber/ios-questions/blob/master/FetchJsonEscapable/FetchJsonEscapable/Views/TopRow.swift) the following code is being used:

```
struct TopRow: View {
    let model:Top
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(model.given)
                .font(.headline)
            Spacer()
            VStack {
                Text("Elo rating: \(model.elo)")
                Text("Average time: \(model.avg_time ?? "")")
                Text("Average score: \(String(model.avg_score ?? 0.0))")
            }
            Spacer()
            DownloadingImage(url: model.photo ?? "TODO")
                .frame(width: 75, height: 75)
        }
    }
}
```

How to change it please, so that the given names on the left side have the same width?

And the stats in the middle too? (the both widths do not have to be equal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your middle content size is the same for all the list rows, then you can use `.fixedSize` and frame.

```
var body: some View {
    HStack {
        Text(model.given)
            .font(.headline)
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity) //<-- Here
        Spacer()
        VStack {
            Text("Elo rating: \(model.elo)")
            Text("Average time: \(model.avg_time ?? "")")
            Text("Average score: \(String(model.avg_score ?? 0.0))")
        }.fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false) //<-- Here
        Spacer()
        DownloadingImage(url: model.photo ?? "TODO")
            .frame(width: 75, height: 75)
    }
}
```